# How do I vectorize %in% (aka match) in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to simulate the Monty Hall problem in probability theory using R. If you are not familiar, the problem goes like this:

*A contestant is on a game show and is told that a prize is behind one of three doors. They are asked to guess a door. After guessing a door, the host (aka Monty Hall) opens a door the prize is not in to help the contestant. The contestant is then allowed to change their guess from their original door to the other door that is still closed. Although not intuitive, the probability of the contestant winning the prize is larger if they change their guess.*

I figured out how to simulate the problem using `for` loops in R, but the code is very slow when I use millions of iterations. I have been trying to vectorize the code and ran into an issue when trying to vectorize the `%in%` function in R. I was wondering if anyone knew how. I am only showing my code for the main section I cannot vectorize. It is identifying the door that the contestant can change their guess to.

```
for (i in 1:f) {
    change[i] <- doors[i, !(doors[i, ] %in% c(guess[i], open[i]))]
}
```

- `f` is number of iterations in the simulation (aka number of random
  contestants).
- `doors` is a matrix with `f` rows with each row equal to
  `c(1, 2, 3)` corresponding to the three doors in the game.
- `guess` is the contestant's original guess.
- `open` is the door the host opened.
- `change` is the door the contestant can change their guess to.

Here is the full code for those who are interested:

```
# MONTY HALL PROBABILITY PROBLEM SIMULATION ####
montyHall <- function(f = 100, change = TRUE) {

  # randoms
  option <- matrix(data = rep.int(x = c(1, 2, 3), times = f),
                   nrow = f, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  correct <- sample.int(n = 3, size = f, replace = TRUE)
  guess <- sample.int(n = 3, size = f, replace = TRUE)
  result <- data.frame("correct" = correct, "guess" = guess)

  # door selection
  temp <- vector(mode = "list", length = f)
  result[, "door"] <- rep.int(x = -999, times = f)
  for (i in 1:f) {
    temp[[i]] <- option[i, !(option[i, ] %in% c(result[i, "correct"], result[i, "guess"]))]
    if (length(temp[[i]]) == 1) {result[i, "door"] <- temp[[i]]}
    if (length(temp[[i]]) == 2) {result[i, "door"] <- sample(x = temp[[i]], size = 1)}
  }

  # change door
  result[, "change"] <- rep.int(x = NA, times = f)
  for (i in 1:f) {
    result[i, "change"] <- option[i, !(option[i, ] %in% c(result[i, "guess"], result[i, "door"]))]
  }

  # outcomes
  if (change == FALSE) {
    result[, "win"] <- ifelse(result[, "guess"] == result[, "correct"],
                              yes = 1, no = 0)
  }
  if (change == TRUE) {
  result[, "win"] <- ifelse(result[, "change"] == result[, "correct"],
                              yes = 1, no = 0)
  }
  if (!is.logical(change)) {
    stop("the change argument must be logical")
  }
  win <- sum(result[, "win"], na.rm = FALSE)
  # if win = NA then something went wrong

  # output
  output <- round(x = win / i, digits = 2)
  return(output)
}
montyHall(f = 1000000, change = FALSE)
montyHall(f = 1000000, change = TRUE)
```

Comment: The `%in%` function _is_ vectorized in its first argument. If you wnat soemthing that is vectorized in both arguments then perhaps use `pmatch` or `mapply`. (The `Vectorize` function is a wrapper around `mapply`.) HOWEVER, you need to post code that creates the objects you are working with so that adequate testing can be done.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have millions of iterations, you might want to reconsider your approach and maybe use some more elaborate probability estimations. I am not a mathematician, but there are certainly other methods out there than what you are using right now. (?) As @42 said, we would need fully reproducible code to understand your approach. This includes sharing the code for sample data and also custom made functions.

Comment: I apologize. I am still learning exactly how StackOverflow works. I have now posted my full code. I read a bit about `pmatch` and it appears that is a vectorized version of `match` (aka `%in%`)? It seems that function might be exactly what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

the set difference you're trying to get could be achieved using `setdiff` (see [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/prob/versions/1.0-1/topics/setdiff)). also, advise this [basic tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/) on how to one-line loops.
consider the following code for your needs:

```
f <- 10
doors <- matrix(rep(1:3,f),nrow=f, byrow = T)
guess <- sample(1:3,f,replace = T)
change <- rep(0,f)
open <- sample(1:3,f,replace = T)
sapply(1:f,function(x) setdiff(doors[x,],c(guess[x], open[x])))
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Thank you for the suggestion. I have used the "apply" family of functions in R before. I never thought to input row indices as the "X" argument in `sapply` though. I assume that is faster than a `for` loop in R?